# Use the pumping lemma to show that the language is not regular

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

I am working on this problem : Use the pumping lemma to show that the language $\{0^n 1^{n} \mid n ≥ 1\}$ is not regular.
May someone give me some suggestion about how to solve this problem?

Comment: Suggestion: see how other proofs of similar statements using the pumping lemma work. They all work the same way, and this problem is almost a textbook example (hint: it's the same as 0^n 1^n 11, reducible to simply 0^n 1^n), so mimicking any textbook proof which uses the pumping lemma should work here.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/). As it stands it looks like your question is covered by http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1031/755.

Comment: **Why did you change the language after the question had been answered?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $L=\{0^n1^{n+2}| n\geq1\}$ is regular and choose the word $\sigma=0^N 1^{N+2}$(with $N$ the pumping lemma constant) to find a contradiction.